# Gnuplot with surface plot and points

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, points, geometry-surface

I tried to do it like suggested in other posts. But the points were not printed. Where is my mistake:

```
set decimalsign locale
set datafile separator ";"

set table 'point_data.dat'
    unset dgrid3d
    splot './points.csv' u 1:2:3
unset table

#set pm3d implicit at s
#set pm3d interpolate 1,1 flush begin noftriangles hidden3d 100 corners2color mean
set dgrid3d 50,50,50

set output 'field.pdf'

splot './point_data.dat' u 1:2:3 w points pt 7, \
      './field.csv' u 2:1:3 with lines lt 5 lc rgb "#000000"

set output
exit
```

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your issue is the `datafile separator`.
If you look at the `point_data.dat`file, I'm sure it will list your points in columns but not separated by `;`. Thus, when you attempt to plot both the `point_data.dat` and the `field.csv` (which I assume is separated by `;` as well), the points will most likely not be plotted because gnuplot cannot interpret the `point_data.dat`-file (which uses the default separator of `" "`).
There are two ways to overcome this:

1. Do not use `set datafile separator`. Instead, use `awk` to remove the `;` while plotting:

   ```
   set decimalsign locale
   set table 'point_data.dat'
   unset dgrid3d

   splot "< awk 'BEGIN {FS=\";\"} {print $1, $2, $3}' points.csv" u 1:2:3

   unset table
   set dgrid3d 50,50,50

   splot "point_data.dat" u 1:2:3 w points pt 7, \
         "< awk 'BEGIN {FS=\";\"} {print $1, $2, $3}' field.csv" u 2:1:3 with lines lt 5 lc rgb "#000000"
   ```

   A few things to notice:

   - inside the `awk`-command, do not forgot to use backslashes with the quotation marks: `\"` or else it will mess up the command (and result in an error).
   - consider unsing `not` to suppress a legend entry or use a defined title (e.g. `title "points"`), otherwise the whole `awk`-command will be printed as title.
2. You can use the `multiplot`-command (and skip the `set table`):

   ```
   set datafile separator ";"

   set xrange [xmin:xmax]
   set yrange [ymin:ymax]
   set zrange [zmin:zmax]

   set multiplot
   splot "points.csv" u 1:2:3 w points pt 7 not
   set dgrid3d 50,50,50
   splot "field.csv" u 2:1:3 with lines lt 5 lc rgb "#000000" not
   unset dgrid3d
   unset multiplot
   ```

   A few things to notice:

   - use `not` to print without legend, or else they will overlap. If you need a legend, you cannot use `multiplot` like this, because they will overlap.
   - set the `xrange`, `yrange` and `zrange` before you plot, or else the axis ranges might not agree. (Be sure to replace `xmin`etc with the actual values from your data range).

Comment: I think the first option is the best, because using `multiplot` for this requires also, that you unset many things before the second `plot` (border, tics, labels). Otherwise the plot might look ugly in some terminals because drawing things twice results in a different anti-aliasing. And if you remove the labels and tics you need to fix the margins with e.g. `set lmargin at screen 0.2`.